# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to select options within a drop down box

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to create a script that can automate clicking of the drop down box and clicking on the option that I want it to. I've tried implementing the code from another similar question, however I got an error message.

Using a solution from a similar question, I tried this line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='interface']/option[text()='Management']").click()
```

HTML

```
<select class="col-1 custom-select" name="interface" id="interface" required="required">
  <option selected="" disabled="" class="hideoption">Select Interface</option>
  <option value="InterfaceLAN">Production</option>
  <option value="MgmtLAN">Management</option>
  <option value="Clustering">Clustering</option>
</select>
```

I would like to automate the process of clicking on the dropdown box and selecting the option 'Management'. However, I received an error message as shown:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@name='interface']/option[text()='Management']"}
```

Comment: @Andersson Now as you have decided to delete your answer for this question, it is totally unethical to forcefully _Close_ this discussion as a _Duplicate_. It is a clear case of **abusing** the _privilege_ offered to you to single-handedly close questions as _duplicates_ being a _Gold Badge_ holder with `selenium` tag.

Comment: @DebanjanB Isn't it *totally unethical* to post a duplicate answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the desired element is a `select` element you need to use the `Select` class and induce *WebDriverwait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# other lines of code
select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='interface' and @name='interface']"))))
select.select_by_value("MgmtLAN")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Select Class , provide the xpath of dropdown there.
Then try to select the dropdown by either value, index or visible text

Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('name'))
select.select_by_index(index)
select.select_by_visible_text("text")
select.select_by_value(value)
```